# Vaadin - Add Duplicate Item in Tree

Tags: tree, duplicates, vaadin

I am doing a project in Vaadin 7. In that, I need to add a duplicate Item in a Tree.

I need a tree like this,

```
+ Person A
    Name
    Age
+ Person B
    Name
    Age
```

But, Vaadin Tree component is not adding the Duplicate item in the tree. It seems like it is overwriting the previous item.

Is it possible to have a tree like above in Vaadin? I use hierarchical container.

**Update**

```
    Object a = "a";
    Object b = "b";
    Object c = "c";
    Object d = "d";
    Object e = "a";
    Object alphabet = "alphabet";

    HierarchicalContainer aHC = new HierarchicalContainer();
    aHC.addItem(a);
    aHC.addItem(b);
    aHC.addItem(c);
    aHC.addItem(d);
    aHC.addItem(e);
    aHC.addItem(alphabet);
    aHC.setParent(a, alphabet);
    aHC.setParent(b, alphabet);
    aHC.setParent(c, alphabet);
    aHC.setParent(d, alphabet);
    aHC.setParent(e, alphabet);

    Tree tree = new Tree();
    tree.setContainerDataSource(aHC);
```

Since Object a and e has the same value as 'a'. The tree just skips or replaces it.

**Dynamic Code**

```
String[] items = {"alphabet", "a", "b", "c", "d", "a"};
for(String item : items) {
   Object itemId = tree.addItem();
   tree.setItemCaption(itemId, item);
}
```

Now how can I set alphabet as parent to all other items?

Comment: could you show us some code how you add your items and which container you use?

Comment: hey Nexus, I have updated my question. Maybe it will help you to find the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `a.equals(e) == true`. So the hierarchical container doesn't add it twice.

You could do two things:

1)

```
Object itemId = select.addItem();
select.setItemCaption(itemId, "The Sun");
```

more information [here](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.selecting.html).

2) Use a POJO object which implements for example `toString()` and set there your item caption or use another item caption mode with `select.setItemCaptionMode(Select.ITEM_CAPTION_MODE_XYZ);`

more information [here](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.selecting.html) as well.

*According to your edit:*
After you added your child item:

```
tree.setParent(itemChildId, itemAlphabetId);
```

see the example [here](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.tree.html).

Comment: Heh nexus.. I have a problem with it.. My tree is a dynamic one.. How can I handle the Objects?

Comment: @Gugan what do you mean by dynamic one?

Comment: Check my "Dynamic Code" Update

Answer (score 0):

The key is having unique id's for each item and modify the captions. Something like:

```
String[] items = {"alphabet", "a", "b", "c", "d", "a"};
int counter = 1;
for(String item : items) {
   Object itemId = tree.addItem(counter);
   tree.setItemCaption(counter, item);
   if(counter >1) {
     tree.setParent(counter, 1);
   }
   counter++;
}
```

By definition the tree can't have multiple items with the same id.

Answer (score 0):

I have done the below things ot access it

Class Menu

```
public class Menu implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4788509071437681011L;
    private String nodeName;

    public Menu(String nodeName) {
        this.nodeName = nodeName;
    }
    public Menu() {
    }
    public String getNodeName() {
        return nodeName;
    }
    public void setNodeName(String nodeName) {
        this.nodeName = nodeName;
   }
}
```

Class MenuCaption

```
public class MenuCaption implements ItemCaptionGenerator<Menu>{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5863017672993685887L;

    @Override
    public String apply(Menu item) {
        return item.getNodeName();
    }
}
```

ViewClass method

```
private void loadMenu() {
TreeData<Menu> menuTreeData = new TreeData<>();
Menu menu = null;
Menu childMenu = null; 
Tree<Menu> menuTree =  new Tree<>();
    try {
        menu = new Menu("General");
        menuTreeData.addItem(null, menu);

        menu = new Menu("Eze");
        menuTreeData.addItem(null, menu);
        childMenu = new Menu("Investor Activity");
        menuTreeData.addItem(menu, childMenu);
        childMenu = new Menu("Investor Statement");
        menuTreeData.addItem(menu, childMenu);

        menu = new Menu("Investran");
        menuTreeData.addItem(null, menu);

        menu = new Menu("VPM");
        menuTreeData.addItem(null, menu);
        childMenu = new Menu("Investor Activity");
        menuTreeData.addItem(menu, childMenu);
        childMenu = new Menu("Investor Statement");
        menuTreeData.addItem(menu, childMenu);

        TreeDataProvider<Menu> dataProvider = new TreeDataProvider<Menu>(menuTreeData);
        menuTree.setDataProvider(dataProvider);
        menuTree.setItemCaptionGenerator(new MenuCaption());
        this.mainHorizontalSplitPanel.setFirstComponent(menuTree);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Output something looks like

```
General
>Eze
    Investor Activity
    Investor Statement
Investran
>VPM
    Investor Activity
    Investor Statement
```